# Laravel model scope activated_at and deactivated_at check if has 7 day difference

Tags: php, laravel, model, scope, eloquent

Using a model scope:

```
public function scopeApproved($query)
{
    return $query->where('activated_at', '>=', 'deactivated_at' -7 days);
}
```

I know that this is invalid syntax but thought it might be clear what i am trying to achieve.

'activated_at' and 'deactivated_at' are two fields in the same table i would like to get all instances where they are more then 7 days apart

Comment: What is the expected behavior when one or both of columns are NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a proper way to achieve this via Eloquent, though you can use MySQL function [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff). Try something like :

```
// in your model
public function scopeApproved($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("DATEDIFF('activated_at','deactivated_at') >= 7");
}
```

This is dependant on the database driver you are using (ie. MySQL, SQLite, SQL server, ...)

**EDIT:**

Found something else that works (so far) with MySQL :

```
// in your model
public function scopeApproved($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("TO_DAYS(activated_at) - TO_DAYS(deactivated_at) >= 7");
}
```

[TO_DAYS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days) being a build in MySQL function.

Comment: Have you tried without the quotes surrounding the fields ? Like `$query->whereRaw("DATEDIFF(activated_at,deactivated_at) >= 7");`

Comment: What database driver are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Shempigon answer is almost correct it only has one issue, you don't wrap the columns name in single quote and also the dates have to be switched, something like this:

```
public function scopeApproved($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("DATEDIFF(deactivated_at, activated_at) >= 7");
}
```

This is because expects this input: `DATEDIFF(endDate, starDate)`, you can read more about DATEDIFF [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)